# Reparenting prefabs between to panels in Unity3d (NGUI)

Tags: c#, parent-child, unity-game-engine, ngui

Not sure this is the best forum for Unity3d/NGUI questions but give it a try...

I am trying to move a gameobject from a scrollable panel to a normal panel by reparenting it.

```
firstGameObject.transform.parent = secondGameObject.transform;
```

firstGameObject is initially child of a clipped scrollable panel. The transform seems to move just fine in the hierarchy and no longer becoming scrollable. But it is still clipped like it was a child of the clipped panel.

Any ideas?

Edit: Someone at NGUI's forum suggested calling Refresh() on both uipanels, but it had no effect. http://www.tasharen.com/forum/index.php?topic=1941.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it working. The correct way was to call CheckParent() on each widget in the old panel after reparenting.

```
UIPanel smallPanel = NGUITools.FindInParents<UIPanel>(firstGameObject);
List<UIWidget> list = new List<UIWidget>(smallPanel.widgets.buffer);

foreach (UIWidget widget in list)
{
    if (widget != null)
    {
        widget.CheckParent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Function `CheckParent()` is obsolete. Now you can use `ParentHasChanged()` on reparented UIWidget.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what scroll bar are you using. Setting new parent to prefab you only setting new local coordinate system to it. You saing that objects in this scroll bar are clipping. So, there must be an array or list or something like that, storing your prefab and making some actions on your prefab. Or, there is some kind of mask, that hides ALL objects in specific area (I think that is your case). In that case you should move your prefab out of mask's area. If you don't need to change screen position, change only Z coordanate, so prefab will becom closer to camera, and out of mask area.

Comment: Here is an example of a clipped panel: http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/ex7.html and some explanation: http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=706 Changing the Z-value does not allow you to make content visible. You're probably right, that there are some internal list of widgets that are to be clipped within UIPanel and that reparenting it does not remove the sprite from this list. So the question is how to tell UIPanel that some of it's children are gone?

Comment: Just remove this prefab from scroll bar's item list. There must be such a list: you probably added your items into it. Just serch it for matching this GameObject and remove from list.

Comment: There are no public list available that holds the prefabs. There is a list of widgets, probably generated by its children hierarchy at initialization. But it does not help me. Tried to expose UIPanels RemoveTransform method, but it did not work. Calling Refresh() on the panel did nothing either.

Comment: You may try to clone object, place it where ever you whant, end just delete original prefab. But It looks like it will be not easy to put it back.